# nodejs- request module- streaming multiple responses from request to http.ServerResponse

Tags: node.js, express, request, streaming, piping

Is it possible to stream responses from multiple requests to http server response?

in expressjs, something like-

```
router.get('/streamingApi',(req,res)=> {
 request('http://localhost:3000/first').pipe(res);  //take 300 ms
 request('http://localhost:3000/second').pipe(res);   //take 100 ms  
 request('http://localhost:3000/third').pipe(res);    // take 200 ms
}
```

The idea is to return the stream to browser as it arrives (when we get the response for second api which is the fastest, stream it to browser, then third api response and last the response of first api)  .

But when I run the above code, only the first response get piped and then the connection closes.

is this even doable with stream piping? any suggestions to fix this without using socket.io?

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible to stream them all at once, otherwise you could have a response with mixed or duplicate data.

Also, there is no way to know ahead of time which request is going to finish first, unless you have prior knowledge about the performance of each endpoint. I suppose you could however fire off requests to all three endpoints and only stream the one that responds the quickest (aborting the other two at that point), however that is not necessarily a guarantee that that stream will finish before the others would have.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need all 3 responses, not just the first one. but dont want to wait for all 3 requests to finish.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish then. You're wanting to buffer all 3 responses and *then* send that back to the client? If you need all 3 responses and you don't want to wait for them to finish, how do you expect to deliver them all to the client?

Comment: mscdex- that is what Iam also wondering if there is a way to do it. . One way I was able to achieve was using websockets. but scaling websockets application is not that straightforward. so iam trying to see if we can do this with regular http calls. thanks for response.